# Programmatically scrolling a CollectionView to end causes exception "Invalid Target Position"

Tags: xamarin.forms

The above header refers.

I am trying to implement a chatting app. There are no compilation errors but whenever it starts running and gets to this line:

```
MessageList.ScrollTo(viewModel.Messages.Last(), null, ScrollToPosition.End, true);
```

it triggers this error:

"Invalid target position".

This is the stack trace:

"Ex = {Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid target position
at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00068] in /Use..."

This is the ChatView.xaml file where MessageList is defined:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:selectors="clr-namespace:Chat.Selectors" 
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Chat.Converters" 
             x:Class="Chat.Views.ChatView">
    
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <selectors:ChatMessageSelector x:Key="SelectMessageTemplate" />
        <converters:Base64ToImageConverter x:Key="ToImage" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ScrollView>
        <ScrollView.Orientation>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ScrollOrientation">
                <On Platform="iOS" Value="Vertical" />
                <On Platform="Android" Value="Neither" />
            </OnPlatform>
        </ScrollView.Orientation>
        <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="1" />
                <RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition.Height>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="GridLength">
                            <On Platform="iOS" Value="50" />
                            <On Platform="Android" Value="100" />
                        </OnPlatform>
                    </RowDefinition.Height>
                </RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <CollectionView x:Name="MessageList" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" 
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SelectMessageTemplate}">
            <CollectionView.Resources>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <DataTemplate x:Key="SimpleText">
                        <Grid Padding="10">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Frame StyleClass="remoteMessage" HasShadow="false" BackgroundColor="#F04D6A">
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Username}" StyleClass="chatHeader" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Text}" StyleClass="chatText" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>

                    <DataTemplate x:Key="LocalSimpleText">
                        <Grid Padding="10">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Frame Grid.Column="1" StyleClass="localMessage" HasShadow="false" BackgroundColor="#24A43B">
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Username}" StyleClass="chatHeader" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Text}" StyleClass="chatText" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>

                    <DataTemplate x:Key="UserConnected">
                        <StackLayout Padding="10" BackgroundColor="#33000000" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Username}" StyleClass="chatHeader" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                            <Label Text="connected" StyleClass="chatText" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>

                    <DataTemplate x:Key="Photo">
                        <Grid Padding="10">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Username}" StyleClass="chatHeader" />
                                <Image Source="{Binding Url}" Aspect="AspectFill" 
                   HeightRequest="150" HorizontalOptions="Fill" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>

                    <DataTemplate x:Key="LocalPhoto">
                        <Grid Padding="10">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <StackLayout Grid.Column="1">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Username}" StyleClass="chatHeader" />
                                <Image Source="{Binding Base64Photo, Converter={StaticResource ToImage}}" 
                   Aspect="AspectFill" HeightRequest="150" HorizontalOptions="Fill" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </CollectionView.Resources>
        </CollectionView>

        <BoxView Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="#33000000" />
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Padding="10">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image Source="photo.png"
         VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="30">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Photo}" />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>

            <Entry Text="{Binding Text}" Grid.Column="1" 
   ReturnCommand="{Binding Send}" />
            <Image Grid.Column="2" Source="send.png"
         VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="30" >
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Photo}" />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

This is the ChatViewModel.cs file:

```
using Acr.UserDialogs;
using Chat.Services;
using Chat.Messages;
using Plugin.Media;
using Plugin.Media.Abstractions;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Chat.ViewModels
{
    public class ChatViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private readonly IChatService chatService;
        public ObservableCollection<Message> Messages { get; private set; }

        public ChatViewModel(IChatService chatService)
        {
            this.chatService = chatService;

            Messages = new ObservableCollection<Message>();

            chatService.NewMessage += ChatService_NewMessage;

            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                if (!chatService.IsConnected)
                {
                    await chatService.CreateConnection();
                }

                await chatService.SendMessage(new UserConnectedMessage(User));
            });
        }

        private string text;
        public string Text
        {
            get => text;
            set => Set(ref text, value);
        }

        public ICommand Send => new Command(async () =>
        {
            var message = new SimpleTextMessage(User)
            {
                Text = this.Text
            };

            Messages.Add(new LocalSimpleTextMessage(message));

            await chatService.SendMessage(message);

            Text = string.Empty;
        });

        public ICommand Photo => new Command(async () =>
        {
            var options = new PickMediaOptions
            {
                CompressionQuality = 50
            };

            var photo = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();

            UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Uploading photo");

            var stream = photo.GetStream();
            var bytes = ReadFully(stream);

            var base64photo = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

            var message = new PhotoMessage(User)
            {
                Base64Photo = base64photo,
                FileEnding = photo.Path.Split('.').Last()
            };

            Messages.Add(message);
            await chatService.SendMessage(message);

            UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
        });

        private void ChatService_NewMessage(object sender, Events.NewMessageEventArgs e)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                if (!Messages.Any(x => x.Id == e.Message.Id))
                {
                    Messages.Add(e.Message);
                }
            });
        }

        private byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                ms.CopyTo(input);

                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }

        private string username;

        public string Username { get => username; set => Set(ref username, value); }

        private ImageSource url;

        public ImageSource Url { get => url; set => Set(ref url, value); }

        private ImageSource base64Photo;

        public ImageSource Base64Photo { get => base64Photo; set => Set(ref base64Photo, value); }
    }
}
```

This is the ChatView.xaml.cs file:

```
using Chat.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Chat.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ChatView : ContentPage
    {
        private ChatViewModel viewModel;

        public ChatView(ChatViewModel viewModel)
        {
            this.viewModel = viewModel;

            InitializeComponent();

            On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOS>().SetUseSafeArea(true);

            viewModel.Messages.CollectionChanged += Messages_CollectionChanged;
            BindingContext = viewModel; 
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            var safeArea = On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOS>().SafeAreaInsets();
            MainGrid.HeightRequest = this.Height - safeArea.Top - safeArea.Bottom;
        }

        private void Messages_CollectionChanged(object sender,
            System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int Kounter = viewModel.Messages.Count;

                //if (Kounter == 1)
                //{
                    //MessageList.ScrollTo(viewModel.Messages.First(), null, ScrollToPosition.Start, true);
                //}                    
                //else
                //{
                    MessageList.ScrollTo(viewModel.Messages.Last(), null, ScrollToPosition.End, true);
                //}
                
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Ex);
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Xamarin.forms version 5.0.0.2515 on Visual Studio version 17.3.

So, what is the issue and how do I sort it out?

Comment: I'd guess that you're attempting to scroll before the CV has rendered the new item

Comment: Ok. Is there a way I could refresh the MessageList CollectionView Object so that when I attempt to scroll to the last item, it should no longer throw this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually scrolling, set `CollectionView`'s `ItemsUpdatingScrollMode` property.

From [Control scroll position when new items are added](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/scrolling#control-scroll-position-when-new-items-are-added):

```cs
<CollectionView ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepLastItemInView">
```

Comment: Funny enough, I did that yesterday

Comment: What if this event is not fired? I have a CollectionView with a set number of items, and I want to scroll to one of them, when the CollectionView loads, and I still get this error

Comment: @TheDeC - if you have not already, create a new question with that. Unfortunately, there is no "clean" solution, because Xamarin lacks a cross-platform event to say when a page has been loaded. The "safe" solution requires writing a custom renderer on each platform to use an appropriate event on each platform. The "hack" solution is to delay 100 ms to 500 msec, then perform the scroll. Wrap the delay and the scroll inside `wrapped inside `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => { try { ... } catch (exception) {}; });` This runs it on main thread (after the delay).

Answer (score 0):

For Chat page I did next: CollectionView Rotation=180 and Content Rotation=180. Works perfect